# Regex to Capture and wrap outline formatted text

Tags: regex

I have source text that is not particularly clean or well formed but I have a need to find text and wrap a line in a tag. The text is in outline format.

```
1. becomes a <h1> tag
A. becomes a <h2> tag
(1) becomes a <h3> tag
and so on...
```

Here are some examples of the source.

> 1. PREPARE FOR TEST A. Open the door. B. Turn on the light.

The desired result would be

```
<h1>1. PREPARE FOR TEST</h1>
<h2>A. Open the door.</h2>
<h2>B. Turn on the light.</h2>
```

Unfortunately, the text could be the same line or it could be on multiple lines or even have a different number of spaces between the outline number and the text. Another example

> (1)   Check air inlet and air outlet valves are shown open if OAT is above > 53.6 deg F., or closed if OAT is below
>
> 48.2 deg F.

In this case the desired result would be

```
<h3>(1) Check skin air inlet and skin air outlet valves are shown open if temperature is above 53.6 deg F., or closed if temperature is below 48.2 deg F.</h3>
```

My questions are

1. How do I find an entire line of text that is associated with an outline level, i.e., the 1., A., (1) and so on.
2. How do I then wrap that text with the appropriate tag.

I'm not particularly strong at regex, I have been able to do some of the simpler things required of this project but this has me stumped a bit. Here's what I used to try to find the H1 lines, but as anyone that knows regex can plainly see, this won't work past the first word.

> \d{1,3}.\s+[A-Z]{2,}

I'm using Python at the moment but am better with PHP and can move to that if needed and still may because I'm better at PHP then Python.

Thank you.

Comment: Does your source file have newline or not?

Comment: Can't count on a newline. We're converting PDFs to text and then trying to parse it out.

Comment: **Not Clear Enough** Where you said: *Here are some examples of the source.* it has no newline

Comment: OK, so how can you tell the difference between a `1.` that starts a new heading and a `1.` that occurs in the text? This appears to be even more problematic with `(1)`...

Comment: In this case "1. PREPARE FOR TEST" we would look for a number, a period and space, and then all upper case words until a space. For these "A. Open the door. B. Turn on the light." we would look for a capital letter, followed by a period and space, and then all the words following. This will be quite complicated.

Comment: Quite complicated is correct. "All the words" needs to be defined more precisely - All the words until when? a full stop?

Comment: You need to write a script or multiple `regex` or may multiple **one-liner**

Comment: Yeah as you can see in "53.6 deg F., " there's an abbreviation in there so can't even count on a '.' as being the end. Argghhh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference and to close this, what I eventually came up with was to run through the entire string of text and remove some trash first. There are actually 15 of these that I use for this step.

```
$regexes['lf'] = "/[\n\r]*/";
$regexes['tab-cr-lf'] = "/\t[\r\n]/";
preg_replace($regexes,"", $string);
```

I then discovered that I could count on space and `\t` after each header identifier, so then I run some more regexes on the string

```
$regexes['step1'] = "/(\d{1,2}\..\t)/";
$regexes['step2'] = "/([A-Z]\. \t)/";
$replacements['step1'] = "\n\n<step1>$0";
$replacements['step2'] = "\n\n<step2>$0";
preg_replace($this->headerRegexes, $replacements, $string);
```

These steps have given me some usable text that I can work with.

Thanks to everyone that chimed in, it gave me somethings to think about as I tackled this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since every regex needs a different substitution, you need to apply each regex in turn. Assuming that you want the match to always span an entire line, I'd suggest something like this:

```
import re
s = """1. becomes a h1 tag
A. becomes a h2 tag
(1) becomes a h3 tag
and so on..."""

regexes = {r"\d+\.": "h1",
           r"[A-Z]+\.": "h2",
           r"\(\d+\)": "h3",
          }

for regex in regexes:
    repl = regexes[regex]
    s = re.sub("(?m)^" + regex + ".*", "<" + repl + ">" + r"\g<0>" + "</" + repl + ">", s)

print(s)
```

Result:

```
<h1>1. becomes a h1 tag</h1>
<h2>A. becomes a h2 tag</h2>
<h3>(1) becomes a h3 tag</h3>
and so on...
```

**Explanation:**

Each of the regexes (which only match the actual identifiers) is modified to match from the start of the line until the end of the line:

```
"(?m)^" + regex + ".*" # (?m) allows ^ to match at the start of lines
```

The entire match is contained in group 0 which can be accessed in the replacement string via `\g<0>`.

```
"<" + repl + ">" + r"\g<0>" + "</" + repl + ">"  # add tags around line
```

Comment: I think the source file have no newline for these 3 part

Comment: Maybe, I'm waiting for OP's answer, too.

Comment: And sometimes the identifier, i.e., "(1)" is on a different line than the text that goes with it!. Argh, dirty data...